# Animate.css button is on wrong position

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, animate.css

if I am trying to do animations with Animate.css, there is a problem with the positioning of the button.
Usually, it is in the footer, but during the fade, it is in the center: 
https://jsfiddle.net/m4f1wen3/

I can't figure out a solution for this for 1 week.

```
<div id="player">
 <header>
  ...
 </header>

 <main>
  ...
 </main>

 <footer>
  <button>Lass uns loslegen!</button>
 </footer>
</div>
```

My aim is that it sticks during the transition to the bottom like after the animation.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace this style in your style

```
header{height: 150px;}
main{height: 200px;}
footer{height:120px; bottom:0; position:relative; width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The animation fadeInLeft adds a translation property to your div and alters the positioning of the footer that has an absolute positioning.

Add this to your style sheet and it will work:

```
html, body, #index, #player {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This will make the html, body and your divs fill the page height and the bottom positioning of your footer will remain in place.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `footer` in CSS selects both footer that is inside `player` div and `index` div.

Adding this to your CSS after `footer` selector

```
#player footer {
  position: relative;
}
```

Removes the problem.

Comment: Theoretically it works, but I positioned the footer absolute because I want that it sticks to the bottom.

Comment: just add a javascript bit to make it fixed as absolute as soon as the animation is done

Comment: @LeonardoCizmar, on another note, Diogo's answer is more graceful, and therefore, IMO, more correct